# Evaluating Internships

Tags: internship

I'm an undergrad student and am confused as to how I would approach evaluating internships. In places like CS, it's easy to know that Google, Facebook, etc would be good places to intern. In other majors, it is more difficult. How would one evaluate the prestige/value of an internship?

Comment: The value of your internship will highly depend on your career plans. I'd suggest asking a couple of teachers to start with.

Comment: @m.raynal Would professors be able to advise about non-academia career advice

Comment: Yes, it's possible that some if them have been in the industry before themselves.

Comment: @user760900 - most undergraduates that professors interact with do not go on to post-graduate studies, much less academia in general. But, what are you asking them to evaluate against?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what "good" means for you.

For example, you claim that as a Computer Science major, doing an internship at Google/ Facebook would be "good". If you are trying to impress your friends, it is most certainly "good". No doubt the name recognition of these companies might help if you are looking for a job in IT where you can convey to recruiters that "I did an internship at Google therefore I am skilled developer".

My personal opinion is that an internship is good if you are able to develop some new skills, learn about yourself in terms of what you like/dislike in terms of workplace environment, job etc. I see it as an opportunity to try things out. I wouldn't place value on an internship solely on the perceived edge it might give you for later employment, although this is a criterion to consider.